# SpringSource Tool Suite: Infinite redirect in vFabric tc server (tomcat)

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, redirect-loop, tcserver

I'm running SpringSource Tool Suite 3.2.0.RELEASE. I have a working application that runs just fine when configured to launch from root context ("/"). I need to move this to a subdirectory (e.g. localhost:8080/myapp ). When I do this in the included tomcat server and then launch the home page, my site goes into an infinite 302 redirect loop.

The site does use Spring Security. However I have a feeling that's not the problem because I've configured log4j to output "trace" messages from all of org.springframework. It happily spits out all the usual startup messages, but when I try to access the home page, it prints absolutely nothing. It's as though the request isn't even getting as far as Spring in the pipeline before the redirect happens. The only evidence I've found in my logs that something is amiss is the recorded 302's in the access log.

How can I debug this problem? SOMETHING is telling the site to redirect somewhere, but I cannot tell what/where/why.

My steps to set the path, in case it helps:

1. Right Click on VMware vFabric tc Server .... and choose "Open"
2. Choose the Modules tab
3. Select my site and choose "edit"
4. Set the path to /myapp (I also tried /myapp/ )
5. Save and restart the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be just a glitch. I removed the website module, saved, cleaned the tc server work directory, re-added it and restarted. Back in business. Hope this helps somebody.